# Error in String class to CString Conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c-strings

I want to put three String variables in one Array besides each other as CString. This code gives me an error for declaration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Str1, Str2, Str3;
    cin >> Str1 >> Str2 >> Str3;

    int length_Str1 = Str1.size(), length_Str2 = Str2.size(), length_Str3 = Str3.size();
    char aCString[length_Str1+length_Str2+length_Str3+1];

    string Str_Array [] = {Str1, Str2, Str3};
    strcpy(aCString, Str_Array.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As per my knowledge, it shouldn't have allowed you to initialize the `length` variables the way you are trying. Kindly post the error message as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is here: http://cpp.sh/2ua2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Errors:**

There were two errors in the code:

`1. 14:32: error: request for member 'c_str' in 'Str_Array', which is of non-class type 'std::string [3] {aka std::basic_string<char> [3]}'
 2. 14:39: error: 'strcpy' was not declared in this scope`

**Reasons:**

> - First error was because you were trying to call `c_str` for a
>     `Str_Array` which is a pointer to the array of strings, the right way
>     is to call it for a string itself i.e. `Str_Array[someIndexOfArray]`
> - Reason behind the second error was that `string.h` which contains the method `strcpy` was not included in the program.

**Solution:**

Try the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <string.h>     //for strcpy and strcat method

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Str1, Str2, Str3;
    cin >> Str1 >> Str2 >> Str3;

    int length_Str1 = Str1.size();
    int length_Str2 = Str2.size();
    int length_Str3 = Str3.size();

    char aCString[length_Str1+length_Str2+length_Str3+1];

    string Str_Array[] = {Str1, Str2, Str3};

    strcpy(aCString, Str_Array[0].c_str()); //copy the first index of array 

    for(int i =1;i<3;i++)   //concatenate each index of array
        strcat(aCString, Str_Array[i].c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried and there is one issue: the only last string saved in the aCString! But I want sth like that: aCString == Str1 Str2 Str3, three strings besides each other. http://cpp.sh/2qza

Comment: I wrote that using for loops to put strings besides each other, but I want sth more efficient if it is possible.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the `strcpy` to `strcat`, basically you have to copy the first index and then all other indices will be concatenated to the output string. See the updated solution.

Comment: Although I am not very good at `Algorithms Analysis` but regarding efficiency, there are two possible methods in my mind:
1 -You can modify the above code and concatenate the strings separately instead of a for loop (program takes n time for input and n time for the concatenation)
2 - You can declare an input array `string inputStr[3]` instead of `Str1,Str2,Str3` and, input and then concatenate the strings using loops (again it will take n + n time)

Comment: As I know this program uses the C library, but I have to write it in pure C++  without using functions from C library. How do you think about that?

Comment: you can easily do it with strings just input the strings and do it like this: `string output = Str1 + Str2 + Str3;
cout << output;`

Comment: It works. There  is any way to contact you directly to ask questions, or remind you about question in stackoverflow?

Comment: No need of it, because there are number of other programmers who are better than me and believe me they are always willing to help you :) by the way you should mark my answer as `accepted` if you really found it useful.